# Resource limits has been reached on GoDaddy (wordpress site)

Tags: wordpress, web, shared-hosting, multisite

I have an issue with my "Multisite WordPress":

- the load time is too slow due to resource limitation on the hosting.

I am using, GoDaddy, 512 MB (Memory). Its a linux server.

As far as I know, for a linux server, this is not a problem to handle 1 WordPress website. There is a little trafic on the web site (20 visitors per day). I optimised the database. All pictures are compressed, PHP 5.6 installed (its the latest one available), cache is enable.

Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Here is some screenshots to better explain the situation. [screenshot from cPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F64cu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having that same issue. GoDaddy wants me to pay to upgrade my resource limits, but I know it shouldn't use that much of my resources (my other similarly low-used sites are hosted with GoDaddy on Level 1 just fine). I have tracked it down so far to the PHP processes. A temporary solution: in cPanel, scroll down to the Software section, click PHP Processes, then click the "Kill Processes" button. However, I am still looking for a plugin or something that keeps causing this recurring issue.